# MySQL pod crashes when connecting to it from other pods (minikube problem)

Tags: kubernetes, devops, minikube, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to setup Helm chart with some dependencies like MySQL, RabbitMQ and so on and when my actual microservice is starting, the moment when first connection is established to MySQL from the microservice, both instantly crash.

It works with **docker-for-desktop** but with **minikube** it doesn't work.

I tried manually to get inside the pod (of microservice and others also) and to try to login to MySQL server (MySQL pod) and it still crashes without any exception
BUT
strange thing is that **if I try to login with wrong credentials for first the time it doesn't crash**, it shows me an error that wrong credentials are in question **and after it if I try with correct ones, it succeeds**!

If I try to login from MySQL pod inside MySQL server it logins correctly.
Curl to MySQL port returns version so it works like it should, only the login to MySQL from external pod is the problem.

Does anyone of you have an idea what's going on here?

Comment: `kubectl logs` might tell you something informative.

Comment: MySQL pod literally nothing but Microservice pod returns me an general exception  "java.io.EOFException" but the problem is not with Microservice pod/app, the problem is when I try to login with MySQL Client and it crashes. I think if we solve the basic one problem, microservice as more general should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can wait for your application to have dependencies ready before requesting them.

You could use [readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/) and [init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to delay your application from starting.

Comment: Tried but waiting isn't the problem.
Problem is when I simply try to login from microservice Pod (I installed mysql client there just for this test) to MySQL server (on MySQL pod) and it instantly crashes the moment I press an enter.